# Autofac returns different instance in asp.net mvc web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I'm using autofac in an asp.net mvc and webapi project.

In the configuration I'm doing this :

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.Register(x => NHibernateConfigurator.BuildSessionFactory()).SingleInstance();
builder.Register(x => x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()).InstancePerHttpRequest();
builder.RegisterSource(new AnyConcreteTypeNotAlreadyRegisteredSource());

builder.RegisterControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

var container = builder.Build();

DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

Now the problem is that in an api controller if I inject ISession via the constructer and also call

```
DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ISession>()
```

it will return 2 different instances.

I'm guessing the problem is because of these 2 lines :

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
```

But how can I make it return the same instance ?

**Edit:**

Just to be more clear - I'm expecting the same instance of ISession per HttpRequest. Right now I'm getting different instances on the same request.

Thanks

Comment: how you registered ISession?

Comment: It's at the top where it says NHibernateConfigurator .. etc and then x.Resolve<ISessionFactory>().OpenSession()

Comment: you are registering it as InstancePerHttpRequest but expecting to have single instance when resolving?

Comment: but i think you are in right direction.cause the session is something specific to request,and it is good to have different instance per request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the answer - it can't be done .. at least not with DependencyResolver.

[ASP .Net 4 Web Api RC + Autofac manual resolving](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11123732/asp-net-4-web-api-rc-autofac-manual-resolving)

I did what it said in the comments, added IComponentContext to the constructor and used that to resolve what I needed.

It seems to be working. Thanks.