# Distinguish between Web API requests and MVC requests in Application handlers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, ioc-container, autofac

I have a rather strange scenario. I am using autofac on a project that has both MVC4 pages and Web API endpoint. Autofac is managing the scope of my model object (which in turn manages the scope of the database context) and I have it configured for `InstancePerHttpRequest` and `InstancePerApiRequest` so that only one database context is created per request. This is so that any database objects that I use are all attached to the same request (the context is an EF6 context).

Here is my strange scenario: The application supports a "proxying" capability where one user can become another for the duration of the page request. In order to make sure that even `AuthorizeAttribute`s pay attention to this, I am catching the request at the `PostAuthenticateRequest` event and performing the `IPrincipal` switch and also setting up the user which my database context uses. The problem comes with a permission check: I need to ask my database if a user is allowed to proxy as the user they would like to proxy as. The code is more or less as follows:

```
protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
{
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return; //nothing to do here if we are not authenticated

    var cookie = Request.Cookies.Get(Controllers.ProxyController.ProxyCookie);

    //The uh-oh occurs at this line...read the rest of the question
    var model = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Model.MyModel>();

    //we load the user initially
    //this sets up the user for the rest of the request since our model object should be shared for everything
    var user = model.Users.Where(u => u.username == User.Identity.Name).FirstOrDefault();
    model.User.Current = model.User.Actual = user;

    if (cookie != null)
    {
        //we ask the database if this user can proxy as the cookie'd username
        var proxyAs = model.Users.Where(u => u.username == cookie.Value).FirstOrDefault();
        if (user != null && proxyAs != null)
        {
            if (user.CanProxyAs(proxyAs))
            {
                //this user is allowed to proxy as the specified user
                string[] roles;
                if (proxyAs != null)
                {
                    //get their roles to replace ours
                    roles = proxyAs.groups.SelectMany(g => g.roles).Select(r => r.name).ToArray();
                }
                else
                {
                    //no roles according to the database
                    roles = new string[0];
                }

                //set the model user stuff
                model.User.Actual = user;
                model.User.Current = proxyAs;

                //save the original user IPrincipal
                HttpContext.Current.Items[Controllers.ProxyController.ProxyUser] = User;

                //we need to set the thread current principal as well to keep it in sync:
                // MVC3 stuff (controllers) appears to use HttpContext.Current.User
                // MVC4 stuff (web api) appears to use Thread.CurrentPrincipal
                Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(new GenericIdentity(cookie.Value), roles);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is at the part where I use the `DependencyResolver` to resolve the model object.

This is not a problem at all for MVC requests...they use the `DependencyResolver` later to create the controllers. The `AutofacDependencyResolver` is a `AutofacDependencyResolver` as set up per the autofac MVC documentation.

For Web API requests, however this is a problem. Since I used the `AutofacDependencyResolver` to resolve the model object in this method, an instance of the model has been instantiated for the `InstancePerHttpRequest` lifetime. However, the WebAPI is going to use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver` which is set up as an `AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver` per the autofac Web API documentation. What ends up happening is that the model object used by a WebAPI call has not had its `model.User` property set up since the MVC `DependencyResolver` gave us back a different model.

I could always set both objects, but then we have context issues. I never know which resolver to use: Should I use the MVC `DependencyResolver` or the Web API dependency resolver?

Further complicating matters is the fact that the web api dependency resolver can only operate in the context of an `HttpRequestMessage` (i.e. inside an Action method). This object is not available during `PostAuthenticateRequest`.

**My questions**

Can I somehow tell autofac that it needs to use the same objects when resolving for both `InstancePerApiRequest` and `InstancePerHttpRequest`?

If that is not possible, is there some way I can:

- Figure out if the request is an API request or MVC request and
- Get the `HttpRequestMessage` during `PostAuthenticateRequest` if it is an API request and use that for dependency resolution?

I may also need to seriously rethink the way I am doing this since this seems at first glance to not be possible per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13549518/autofac-returns-different-instance-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api) answer.

EDIT: I believe I may be able to use a `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler` to intercept the WebAPI request which eliminates the need to obtain the `HttpRequestMessage` during `PostAuthenticateRequest`. However, that still leaves the question of determining if the request is a web api request or not.

Comment: You could manually invoke the routing methods for the given URL and see if the resulting route points to a `Controller` or `ApiController` and go from there perhaps.

Comment: So, supposedly in the latest versions the key should be shared between webapi and mvc, so it should work identically. I've blogged on this subject before though: http://darrenkopp.com/posts/2013/07/02/Getting-Autofac-NServiceBus-ASPNET-MVC-and-Web-API-to-play-together

Comment: I just installed all of this yesterday from NuGet and the assertion `this.Model == DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<Model.MyModel>()` fails when called from the context of a Web API action that had `Model.MyModel` injected via the controller constructor and assigned to `this.Model` which says to me that the instance isn't being shared.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong, it's just that you can provide the key to InstancePerX now for both mvc and web api. see here: http://alexmg.com/new-features-in-the-autofac-310-updates/. you just need to provide the same key i guess? or you can take the approach i did which is simpler, albeit with more initial code up front

Answer (score 0):

When you implement a delegating handler you are guaranteed that your code runs in a Web API request. You can also just make it a global filter.

You can probably implement the MVC portion as a high priority Authorization filter, again you will be guaranteed to be in MVC at that point.